# Return Pymongo result in Python Bottle

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I try to implement a 'kind-of' personal API for my own usage. I work in Python Bottle with Pymongo. Here is my code:

```
@bottle.get('/getscore')
def getscore():
    mode = bottle.request.query.get("mode")

    results = scoredb.find({"mode":mode}).sort("score",-1).limit(5)

    return results (try also return str(results))
```

When I fetch a url like this `www.mywebsite.com/getscore?mode=Mymodetest`, I would like to return the top 5 results of this mode with the highest score. (score is a numeric field).

If I run the code with `return results` I have `Unsupported response type: <type 'dict'>`
. I found a similar question in SO with the answer of using `return str(results)`, but with this one, I have an empty page.

Comment: Try converting the `results` dict to json. Use `import json` and then do `return json.dumps(results)`

Comment: @arun I get `TypeError: <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x109bda150> is not JSON serializable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `json` library, I tried this one and it works.

```
from bson.json_util import dumps

dumps(results)
```